# How I can fix this animation

Tags: animation

So, I want to do an animation of taking the screws out of the box and inserting them into an element and then rotating that element with the screws. To rotate the element I set the parent, when I do this the screws pop out of the box (you can see it at the beginning of the animation), how can I fix it?

https://streamable.com/spvb4v

Comment: You could duplicate the screws and alternate their visibility to swap between parented/not-parented screws.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your screw 2 *Child Of* constraints, one for each object (box and phone), and keyframe their visibility so that the screw stops being the child of one object and begins to be the child of the other. Also use the 3D cursor and keyframe the screw position so that it stays at its position in the 3D scene when you deactivate the visibility. Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: cool idea!!!!!!

Comment: thanks, I didn't go into detail but there's also the apply visual transformation (instead of 3D cursor) if the child is rotated and you need to keep it as it is